# How to access the returned varible from Ipywidgets output widget

Tags: python, pandas

I am using ipywidgets in a class to clean the dataset. Using the ipywidgets output tab, I am able to print the cleaned dataframe, but I am unable to access the returned dataframe variable (df_clean) in the next code cells. I am not sure what am missing here, spent a day exploring...

[Notebook colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RjW_0TKpZYP6dwCvS6nxqovmdLxTvy4O?usp=sharing)

[code_query_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO6ON.png)

```
from ipywidgets import Button
from IPython.display import display,clear_output
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taknev83/datasets/master/credit_risk_train.csv')

class Clean_data():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
            
    def missing_value(self):
        import pandas as pd
        df_clean = self.df.copy(deep=True)
        mis_val = widgets.Dropdown(
                    options = [('Yes', '1'), ('No', '2')],
                    value = '1',
                    description = 'Impute Missing Value',
                    style = {'description_width': 'initial'},     
                    disabled=False)
        display(mis_val)
        button = widgets.Button(description = 'Run Impute')
        out = widgets.Output()
        
        def on_button_clicked(_):
            with out:
                clear_output()
                if mis_val.value == '1':
                    categorical_cols = df_clean.select_dtypes('object').columns.to_list()
                    for col in categorical_cols:
                        df_clean[col].fillna(df_clean[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)
                    numeric_cols = df_clean.select_dtypes(['float64', 'int64']).columns.to_list()
                    for col in numeric_cols:
                        df_clean[col].fillna(df_clean[col].mean(), inplace=True)
#                     print(self.df) print is working
                    print('Completed imputation')
                    return df_clean # where to access this return dataframe?
                if mis_val.value == '2':
                    return df_clean          
            
        button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
        a = widgets.VBox([button, out])
        display(a)
```

I would like to access df_clean in the next code cells for further use...

Comment: then `return df_clean` from the `missing_value` function, or set it to a class variable `self.df_clean = df_clean` (would recommend the former)

Comment: Thanks, the main reason for returning `df_clean` from `on_button_clicked` method is to get the df_clean after selecting the imputation choice & clicking the Run Impute button. If I return `df_clean` from `missing_value` function, it's not waiting for user's impute choice selection & Run impute button click, in this way, as soon as `missing_value` method is called in below cells, it displays the `df_clean` along with widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

Following you can put in your utils.py or whatever you want to call this module.

```
from ipywidgets import Button
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display,clear_output
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taknev83/datasets/master/credit_risk_train.csv')

train.iloc[0, :] = pd.NA
train.isna().sum().sum()

class Clean_data():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
            
    def missing_value(self):
        import pandas as pd
        self.df = self.df.copy(deep=True)
        mis_val = widgets.Dropdown(
                    options = [('Yes', '1'), ('No', '2')],
                    value = '1',
                    description = 'Impute Missing Value',
                    style = {'description_width': 'initial'},     
                    disabled=False)
        display(mis_val)
        button = widgets.Button(description = 'Run Impute')
        out = widgets.Output()
        
        def on_button_clicked(_):
            with out:
                clear_output()
                
                if mis_val.value == '1':
                    categorical_cols = self.df.select_dtypes('object').columns.to_list()
                    for col in categorical_cols:
                        self.df[col].fillna(self.df[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)
                    numeric_cols = self.df.select_dtypes(['float64', 'int64']).columns.to_list()
                    for col in numeric_cols:
                        self.df[col].fillna(self.df[col].mean(), inplace=True)
#                     print(self.df) print is working
                    print('Completed imputation')
                    return self.df # where to access this return dataframe?
                if mis_val.value == '2':
                    return self.df          
            
        button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
        a = widgets.VBox([button, out])
        display(a)
```

In the notebook where you want to import, you can do as follows:

```
from utils import *

# include some NAs just for testing the functionality
train.iloc[0, :] = pd.NA
print(train.isna().sum().sum()) # should print 21


# call the cleaning functionality
c = Clean_data(train)
c.missing_value()
# another check
print(c.df.isna().sum().sum()) # should be 0
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Many thanks, this works fine in the same notebook. But when I am importing this .py file & this Clean_data class in another notebook, am not able to access the defined global variable df_clean in the new notebook environment... any suggestions...

Comment: I would agree with @WBM's comment. Using global variable is not a good programming practice. Rather return it from the function.

Comment: Thanks, the main reason for returning df_clean from on_button_clicked method is to get the df_clean after selecting the imputation choice & clicking the Run Impute button. If I return df_clean from missing_value function, it's not waiting for user's impute choice selection & Run impute button click, in this way, as soon as missing_value method is called in below cells, it displays the df_clean along with widgets, any suggestions...

Comment: You actually do not need any global variables at all. You can encapsulate everything in the class itself. I modified my answer.